# Как дочернему элементу активизироваться по hover родительского?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Как изменить иконку при ховере родительского элемента?

Второй вопрос который надо решить с этим набором как оставить активным этот элемент, после перемещения курсора вне блока?

Что бы можно было быстро получить именно активный блок через JS

```css
.wrk-card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*border: 2px solid #7ac142;*/
  border: 2px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #808080;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12pt;
  line-height: 16px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'clear_sans_thinregular';
  padding-top: 4px;
}
.wrk-card:hover {
  border: 2px solid #7ac142;
  color: #7ac142;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrk-card span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 61px;
}
.calc-balcony span {
  background: url("http://www.trendmicro.com/cloud-content/us/images/icons/contact-dell-logo.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 55px;
}
.calc-lamp span {
  background: url("http://www.trendmicro.com/cloud-content/us/images/icons/contact-dell-logo.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrk-card calc-balcony">
  <span>помыть балкон</span>
</div>
<div class="wrk-card calc-lamp">
  <span>мыть люстры</span>
</div>
```

[image: Набор элементов, например]

Comment: опишите подробнее, что именно вы хотите сделать, `hover` Не активизирует никакой элемент, но поменять стиль дочернему элементу при hover родителя можно, достаточно использовать селектор `parent:hover child` - но никакой связи с js тут нет

Comment: Как JS узнать что был клик по конкретному элементу элементу wrk-card  и активировать его, как при ховере?

Comment: Вообще не понятно, что вы хотите сделать. То hover, то клик. Если у вас два вопроса - задайте два вопроса

Comment: судя по всему вы хотите в обработчике клика поменять класс элементу по которому кликнули, так?

Comment: Да, пожалуй так и сделаю.

Answer (score 3):

На первый вопрос ответил.

```
.calc-balcony:hover>span
```

Comment: `>` не обязательно